# Finding optimal solution through using Kuhn Tucker conditions.

Tags: calculus, optimization, self-learning, maxima-minima

$$max \{ \sqrt{x}+y\}$$

Subject to $$x+2y\le I$$

$$x\ge0$$ $$y\ge 0$$

I want to find the optimal solution by using Kuhn Tucker conditions.

What I do is as follows:

The Lagrangian function

$$L= \sqrt{x}+ y + \lambda [I-x-2y]+\mu_1 [x ] + \mu_2 [y]$$

FOCs

$$\partial L/\partial x= 1/2 x^{-1/2}-\lambda +\mu_1\le 0 $$ $x[1/2 x^{-1/2}-\lambda +\mu_1]=0 $ for $x\ge 0$

$$\partial L/\partial y= 1-2\lambda +\mu_2\le 0 $$

$y[1-2\lambda +\mu_2]=0$ for $y\ge 0$

$$\partial L/\partial\lambda = I- x-2y\ge 0$$

$\lambda [I-x-2y]=0$ for $\lambda \ge 0$

$$\partial L/\partial\mu_1 =x\ge 0$$ $\mu_1 x= 0$ for $\mu_1\ge 0$

$$\partial L/\partial\mu_2 =y\ge 0$$ $\mu_2 y= 0$ for $\mu_2\ge 0$

When I solve this, I found that
$(x^*=1, y^*=\frac{I-1}{2}, \lambda=1/2, \mu_2=\mu_1=0)$

I can only found one optimal solution.

But my instructor states there are more than one solutions. I could not proceed the question.

I will be appreciated for your great helps.

Thank you.

Comment: The other solution is $\sqrt{I}$ at $x^* = I, y^* = 0, \lambda=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{I}},\mu_1 = 0,\mu_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{I}}-1$ as long as $0 < \sqrt{I} < 1$.

Comment: @Cesareo Thank you a lot.